# Delphi: NetHttpClient - How to add/edit/delete HEADER VALUES for XML Requests

Tags: xml, webapi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I am working on an integration with an XML Server into a client application (VCL), with Delphi 10.2. I cannot use Indy HTTP, because the (external third party) server I am using is using SSL and Indy has some issue with the required OpenSLL DLLs, which I do not have a redistribution license for.

So, I am now forced to use the "new" Delphi NetHttpClient components to try and call API functions on this server. I just cannot seem to populate the Request HEADER with Parameters successfully, nor can I read any possible existing HEADER values on my single NetHttpClient component (on a Data Module).

This is what I have tried so far:

```
procedure TfrmMain.CallAPI2;
var
  Params : TStringlist;
  URL, CertKey, CertSerial, CertSerialB64 : String;
  ReqStream : TStream;
begin
  URL := edtURL.Text;
  CertKey := edtCERT.Text;
  CertSerial := edtCertSerial.Text;
  CertSerialB64 := IdEncoderMIME1.Encode(CertSerial);

  ReqStream := TStream.Create;
  memRequest.Lines.SaveToStream(ReqStream);

  //REQUEST HEADER PARAMETERS
  Params := TSTringlist.Create;
  Params.Add('content-type=xml');
  Params.Add('cert-serial=' + CertSerialB64);
  Params.Add('client=webapi');

  //CALL ACTUAL API FUNTION
  memResponse.Text := DM1.REQ1.Post(URL, ReqStream, nil, TEncoding.UTF8, Params).ContentAsString;
  Params.Free;
end;
```

I would appreciate any guidance on:

1. How do I manipulate the Headers, i.e. Adding and deleting new parameters and values?
2. How do I call a POST request with header and payload data that must be sent to the server for evaluation. The method I have tried causes errors.
3. How can I read/view/evaluate what parameter values are already in the NetHttpClient HEADER?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If you feel forced to use NetHttpClient component, you may feel free to use ICS (Internet Component Suite). You can download it using Delphi GetIT! Or download from http://wiki.overbyte.eu/wiki/index.php/ICS_Download. ICS supports only OpenSSL 1.1.1.